# Sub Function VBA

Tags: vba, loops, filter, functional-programming, subroutine

I have a filter based on Team A which looks like this

```
Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").copy  Destination:=Sheets("Team A").Range("A1")

Columns("R:R").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$R$1:$R$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
"Team A"
```

I want to filter the data by the other 8 teams and paste the data into a sheet each.

Is this possible to use a sub routine with parameters so instead of putting team A i can jut put a variable name like R which will loop through the team names that i can reference?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar answer to Gary's - this will do all sheets except 'Data' and doesn't require a separate procedure:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.Name <> "Data" Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
                .Columns("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=wrkSht.Name
                .Range("A:X").Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A1")
            End With
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

To exclude more than the `Data` sheet you could use:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wrkSht.Name
            Case "Data", "SomeOtherSheet"
                'Do nothing.
            Case Else
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
                    .Columns("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=wrkSht.Name
                    .Range("A:X").Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A1")
                End With
        End Select
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, this seems to do the trick with a few adjustments! I need to to skip a few more sheets than Data

Comment: How would i exclude more than "Data"?

Comment: You could use a `Select Case` statement.  I'll add that code to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Hi, Thanks thats brilliant! sorry I am learning as i go with VBA!. next up is making pivot tables with vba for each team!!

Comment: That's weird.  Does it crash if you step through the code row by row (pressing F8) - and if so, on what line?

Comment: I think its cos i have too much data, i have to restart each time so can't really say which line. I have 9 teams to loop through, put into separate sheets and make pivots tables from them so i might need a sub routine and then call it i think

Comment: Try @user3598756 answer - the extra code may stop the crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to create a subroutine like you mention, I may have not understood correctly but like your code was not copying the correct team data to the sheets, the below example counters this but you can always places yours back.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Sample2 "Team A"
Sample2 "Team B"
Sample2 "Team C"
Sample2 "Team D"
Sample2 "Team E"
Sample2 "Team F"
Sample2 "Team G"
Sample2 "Team H"
End Sub

Private Sub Sample2(ByVal StrTeam As String)
Sheets("Data").Range("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=StrTeam
Sheets("Data").Range("A:X").Copy Destination:=Sheets(StrTeam).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I left out the part where i copy and paste into a sheet. I was mainly looking for a way to have 1 filter by each team and paste the data into a sheet for each team. The sheet is called Team A and the data is filtered by Team A

Comment: Hi @user3018495 Did I answer the question?

Comment: Hi, Yes this helped

Answer (score 0):

try this

Option Explicit

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A:X")
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If InStr(ws.Name, "Team") > 0 Then
                .AutoFilter
                .Columns("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=ws.Name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
                .AutoFilter
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub
```